# Can I just Upgrade springframwork to 5.3.18 to avoid CVE-2022-22965?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security

The spring published that:
[image]

I used spring 5.3.16, spring boot 2.2.10.RELEASE, spring cloud 2.2.10.RELEASE to use spring-cloud-netflix-zuul, so, can I just upgrade the spring version to 5.3.18, but don't upgrade other framwork?

Comment: yes you are safe post this upgrade according yo the docs you posted

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot `2.2.x` is EOL and may contain other security fixes that affect you. Spring Boot `2.2.10.RELEASE` [use Spring Framework `5.2.9.RELEASE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html#appendix-dependency-versions).

If you are using Spring Framework `5.3.x`, this is not really a supported scenario irrespective of this CVE. You should be using Spring Framework `5.2.x`. For that, we have released Spring Framework `5.2.20`.

Of course, to be really safe you should upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, our project use the zuul and eureka,I find that spring boot and spring cloud not support these if the version upper than 2.2.x, I use the 2.2.10 to solve this problem. So if I use the spring framework with 5.2.20, and keep the spring boot and spring cloud the old versions--2.2.10.RELEASE, it will fix this VULNERABILITY CVE-2022-22965? thanks again.